# Issue in the TESTNG program when I use "Priority" tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Code: Program using @Test method with priority tags.

```
package testng1;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    @Test 
    public class testng {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public void verifytitle()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\rprem\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://google.com");
        String title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(title);
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "Google");
    }
    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void verifytitle2()
    {
    driver.get("https://gmail.com");
    String titlee = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(titlee, "Gmail - Free Storage and Email from Google");
    }
}
```

When I run the program then I'm getting the "Java null pointer exception" issue. As per the logic methods will be executed in the alphabetical order, when I put the priority then they will run in the given order. But it's not happening like that.

Error message:

```
Google
PASSED: verifytitle
FAILED: verifytitle2
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testng1.testng.verifytitle2(testng.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your test code.

In the method `verifytitle()` please change `WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();` to `driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`

Since you are assigning the `InternetExplorerDriver` instance to a local variable in this method, it is shadowing the class level WebDriver and so when `verifytitle2()`  tries to access it, it triggers a `NullPointerException`

To fix the problem, I would suggest that you extract out the webdriver instantiation logic to a `@BeforeClass` method.

```
@BeforeClass() 
public void beforeClass() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\rprem\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}
```

Comment: Hi Krishnan, thanks for your answer. But it didn't work, still getting null pointer exception.

Comment: @BruceWayne - You would see the `NullPointerException` if you directly attemtped at running `verifytitle2()` because the `WebDriver` instantiation is happening in `verifyTitle()` method.
I have updated my answer to ensure that this doesn't happen